# Starting value problem with the help of separation of values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my college course we got this following starting value problem
$$
y' = r \left(y_∞ - \frac{y}{y_∞}\right),~~~   y(0)=y_0
$$
We have to solve it using the method "separation of values"

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: This is hard to read.  If nothing else, it looks like you jammed two equations next to each other, making it hard to tell where one ends and the other begins.

Comment: You surely mean separation of variables, and it should not be that hard to carry out or to do a linear change of variables that simplifies the equation. Check if your equation is not really $y'=r\frac{y_∞−y}{y_∞}$.

Comment: Is $r$ the independent variable or just a constant?  That is, does $y = y(r)$?

Comment: I don't know what "separation of values" means. May be "separation of variables" ?. Although, what is $y'$ ? is it $\frac{dy}{dr}$ or $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $\frac{dy}{dt}$ or something else ?